# Contenteditable - How to remove html tag with selection text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

how to **remove html tag** in `contenteditable` with **selection text**

```
function testdemo() {
//what is next
....
}
```

**Before :**

```
<button onclick="testdemo();">RUN</button>

<div id="test" contenteditable="true">
  <b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, <span style="color:red;">ea ignota verear</span> quaerendum
</div>
```

**After :**

```
<div id="test" contenteditable="true">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, ea ignota verear quaerendum
</div>
```

**Thank you in advance**

Comment: Please check [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/avj5fhjw/) it's not perfect, but it gives some ideas of what you need to know to achieve what you want.

Answer (score 3):

Try this:

JS:

```
function testdemo() {
   var div = document.getElementById('test');
   div.innerHTML = div.textContent;
}
```

Jquery:

```
function testdemo() {
   $('#test').html($('#test').text());
}
```

Comment: **text selection** means ?

Comment: @SisiSajah I don't quite understand either

Comment: @SisiSajah I think you means selected part of text.

Answer (score 1):

jQuery version would be as below:

```js
function testdemo() {
  $("#test").html($("#test").text());
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="testdemo();">RUN</button>

<div id="test" contenteditable="true">
  
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function testdemo() {
   var div = document.getElementById('test');
   div.innerHTML = div.textContent;
}
```

```html
<button onclick="testdemo();">RUN</button>

<div id="test" contenteditable="true">
  <b>Lorem ipsum</b> dolor sit amet, <span style="color:red;">ea ignota verear</span> quaerendum
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

See if this helps.

```
function testdemo() {
$('#test').html($('#test').text()).text();​
}
```